# Java dcm4che FindSCU

Tags: java, dcm4che

I want to do a C-FIND to a pacs from java. I have seen the FindSCU.java class in the dcm4chee library but I don't know how to implement it. I've been looking for a couple of hours and haven't found any information about it. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: You need to create an `Association` object (which you can create through a `NetworkApplicationEntity`).  _This_ object has a `cfind` method, which takes a `DicomObject` (which is just an empty `DicomObject`, with whatever tags you're looking for your CFind to filter on included).  I'm afraid I don't have time to write a full answer with code here.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'm going to try with that.

Comment: No problem, I might be able to be more helpful later (I just don't have a PACS set up to test any code against right now).  If you feel there's any documentation missing on the dcm4che codebase (there is...  Lots missing...) which you'd like to add, the project's open to pull requests.

Comment: Ok, so I made the association work and get the same result as I get from FindSCU.java. The problem now is that it stays forever here: 15:50:50.293 [main] DEBUG org.dcm4che3.net.Association - AEDOWN->ORTHANC(1): enter state: Sta5 - Awaiting A-ASSOCIATE-AC or A-ASSOCIATE-RJ PDU

Comment: So, (I believe) the code would look like:
```
DimseRSP dimseRsp = assocation.cfind(...);
while (dimseRsp.next()) {
    DicomObject commandDO = rsp.getCommand();
    if (CommandUtils.isPending(commandDO)) {
        dicomObjects.add(rsp.getDataset());
    }
}
```
(Where `dicomObjects` is some `Collection` of `<DicomObject>`s which you're planning to return.)

Comment: _But_, it looks like it's stuck awaiting on acquiring the association, in which case, are you sure your orthanc PACS is responding to CFinds?

Comment: I've also tried another pacs and it doesn't work for me. For now I'm going to look for another solution since I can't spend more time on this. When I can, I'll try again.